# What do these columns mean in db performance chart?

Tags: database, clickhouse

There are two subcolumns below ClickHouse (1.1.53960). What do two columns means?

Please give me an advice. Thank you.

[image]

Chart URL: https://clickhouse.yandex/benchmark.html#[1000000000,[%22ClickHouse%22,%22Vertica%22],[%220%22,%221%22]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means two consecutive runs of the same test. It's used to compare the performance when data is in cache or not, i.e. cold data v.s. hot data.